# Can you pass multiple filter parameters from a custom provider web part to a list view web part?

Tags: list-view, list-view-web-part

I've created a custom provider web part that I would like use to pass multiple filter parameters to a list view web part. Is this possible?

If so, is there an example or tutorial out there that shows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using webpart connections. If so, You cannot do this.

A webpart can only be connected to another webpart through one connection type and
Each connection can have only one connection type.

So, you cannot establish two connections between same instance of Provider and Consumer webpart. However, You can connect a provider web part with two instance of same consumer webpart (if the provider expose two connections points).

A web part provider can make multiple connection points available, while a web part consumer can
consume multiple provider connection points. In that case, every connection point requires a unique ID
on both the consumer side and the provider side by specifying the connection point
ID in the [ConnectionProvider] attribute.

A good option is to use filter values from query string.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Another solution I came up with is to create a new consumer webpart that inherits the ListView Web Part class. I then pass in a CSV list of values that are then parsed and create a view on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link from [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735844/itransformablefiltervalues-interface-with-two-or-more-parameters-sharepoint-web) site can help you to create multiple filter webpart

OR

You can passing two or more filter parameter by using query string web part. This [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-query-string-url-filter-web-part-to-another-web-part-HA010250999.aspx) will give you tutorial how to use query string webpart to filter list item. You can use custom control to add query string to your site url.

Hope it solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add several list filters through sharepoint designer but you cant do this through the front end web page